# Factory Pattern Contracts in Solana

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

Is there a way to implement a factory pattern contracts with rust on solana? Is it similar to the ethereum way? Please show an example.

Went through discord and docs, probably missed it, but couldn't find an answer.

What is the workaround, if missing?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, the answer is that it is an anti-pattern, better not do that. Learned it [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/239/how-to-write-a-factory-pattern-contracts-in-solana/260#260)

But if you want to try, a workaround probably exists, and it might be smth like (didn't succeed, but maybe you will):

```
cargo build-bpf 
solana program write-buffer
```

after that use functions like [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/cli/src/program.rs#L1741)
got help from discord solana tech server